# List<string> Only displaying last item

Tags: c#

Trying to make a list out of a string of part names. It's skipping displaying all the names except the very last one in the list.. Why is it doing this? Is there a better way of doing this?
*My Code behind*

```
    List<string> Ta1PartNumbers = ta1input.Split('\n').ToList<string>(); //Trying to split at the line break.. Would this be the proper way to do it?

    foreach (string Tpartnumber in TramPartNumbers)
    {
        Div1.InnerText = (Tpartnumber);
    }
```

List is like so:
**Part_numbers

1017foo

1121bar

etc..**

Comment: I'd split like this: `ta1input.Split('\n', '\r', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();` - just to make sure that you aren't missing the CR character.

Comment: You can also just get rid of the `ToList()` and go with this: `var Ta1PartNumbers = ta1input.Split('\n', '\r', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're resetting the innerText value each iteration of the loop, so it only retains the last one. Try appending with the `+=` operator

```
foreach (string Tpartnumber in TransimPartNumbers)
{
    Div1.InnerHtml += Tpartnumber + "<br />";
}
```

Comment: You'd need to use `InnerHtml`, lest the `<br />` be escaped and replaced with `&lt;br /&gt;`.  But then, only if you trust the source string.

Comment: Rather than all that string concatenation and looping, you could just do `Div1.InnerHtml = ta1input.Replace("\n", "<br/>")`.  Of course, the use of `InnerHtml` would never pass code review where I work because of the security hole - injecting user input directly as html.

Answer (score 1):

I make this mistake more than I should. Try:

```
Div1.InnerText = "";
foreach (string Tpartnumber in TransimPartNumbers)
{
   Div1.InnerText += (Tpartnumber);
}
```

You are basically overwriting the previous value each time.

Comment: John E, including a signature at the end of your post is not necessary and is discouraged. If you notice, there is a little card with a name and link to your account under each and every post.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using a List where you don't need to.  Use this split method instead, but I think you want \r\n...  And like the other posters, you needed += which appends, rather than + which updates.

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(ta1input, "\r\n");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Div1.InnerText += Tpartnumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of your loop replaces the `InnerText` of `Div1` with the current string.  This is why you are only getting the last string, you wrote over all the previous strings.

But, why even split the string?  If you just want to write all of the strings to the div, you can just do:

```
Div1.InnerText = ta1Input;
```

What do you want as your final HTML?

```html
Part_numbers<br/>
1017foo<br/>
1121bar<br/>
etc..<br/>
```

Or

```html
<div>Part_numbers</div>
<div>1017foo</div>
<div>1121bar</div>
<div>etc..</div>
```

Or something else?  Personally, I prefer the latter.  I'd do something like this:

```
string[] Ta1PartNumbers = ta1input.Split('\n');

foreach (string Tpartnumber in Ta1PartNumbers)  
{
    var div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.InnerText = Tpartnumber;
    Div1.Controls.Add(div);
}
```